# onblur function for array of values

Tags: javascript

This is my full code

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

   <head>
 <style>
    body  {
   background-image:url("rice.png");
  }
  </style>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script> 
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />



  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/print.css' media="print" 
/>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js'></script>
   <script type='text/javascript' src='js/example.js'></script>
   </head>

    <body>
     <form name="form1" method="post" class="register" action="<?php echo 
     $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" >

     <div id="page-wrap">

      <textarea id="header">PURCHASE</textarea>

       <div id="identity">

         <textarea id="address" disabled>AR Traders  Address:
        </textarea >

        <div id="logo">

          <div id="logoctr">
            <a href="javascript:;" id="change-logo" title="Change    
 ">Change Logo</a>
            <a href="javascript:;" id="save-logo" title="Save 
        changes">Save</a>
            |
            <a href="javascript:;" id="delete-logo" title="Delete 
       logo">Delete Logo</a>
            <a href="javascript:;" id="cancel-logo" title="Cancel changes">Cancel</a>
          </div>

          <div id="logohelp">
            <input id="imageloc" type="text" size="50" value="" /><br />
            (max width: 540px, max height: 100px)
          </div>
          <img id="image" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>

    <div id="customer">
     <br>
        <textarea id="customer-title">Widget Corp.
        c/o Steve Widget</textarea>

        <table id="meta">
            <tr>
                <td class="meta-head">Invoice #</td>
                <td><textarea name="invoice"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td class="meta-head">Date</td>
                <td><input type="date" name="date" /><br></td>
            </tr>


        </table>

       < /div>


     <fieldset class="row2">
            <legend>Product Details</legend>
            <p> 
                <input type="button" value="Add Product" 
        onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
                <input type="button" value="Remove Product" 
      onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')"  /> 

            </p><br>
           <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
              <tbody>
                <tr class="j">
                  <p>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" 
      name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <label>Product Details</label>
                        <input type="text" required="required" 
    name="product[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <label for="brand">Brand</label>
                        <input type="text" class="small"  name="brand[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <label for="s_brand">Sub Brand</label>
                        <input type="text" required="required" class="small"  
 name="s_brand[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <label for="qty">Quantity</label>
                        <input type="text" required="required" class="small" 
  id="qty"  name="qty[]" onblur="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <label for="prate">Purchase Rate</label>
                        <input type="text" required="required" class="small" 
 id="prate" name="prate[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <label for="tax">Tax</label>
                        <select id="tax" name="tax" required="required">
                            <option value="0">0</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                        </select>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <label for="srate">Selling Price</label>
                        <input type="text"  class="small"  name="srate[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <label for="amt">Total Purchase Amount</label>
                        <input type="text" required="required" class="small" 
  id="amt" name="amt[]">
                     </td>
                        </p>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <script>

     document.getElementById("tax").onblur = function(){
    var tin1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("qty").value) * 
   parseFloat(document.getElementById("prate").value)
  var tin = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tax").value) / 100
   document.getElementById("amt").value = tin  +  tin1
   }
    </script>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </fieldset>
      <input class="submit" name="add" type="submit" value="Confirm &raquo;" 
  />

        <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="terms">
      <h5>Terms</h5>
      <textarea disabled>Designed by Kshathriya Technologix.</textarea>
    </div>

  </div>
  </form>
 </body>

</html>
```

This is my script and form. When I click add button, the form gets added.

The script works only for first form, while I am adding additional forms, the script does not works for them.

This is my full code for design and it's working only for first form and not for the other additional forms which I am adding later.

I pasted my full form code in this.

[image: See image]

example.js

```
  function addRow(tableID)
  {
   var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
   if(rowCount < 20){                           
      var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
      var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
     for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
         var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
   }else{
      alert("Maximum Product submitted is 20.");

   }
 }

 function deleteRow(tableID) {
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
   for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
     var row = table.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
     if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
        if(rowCount <= 1) {                         
            alert("Cannot Remove all the Passenger.");
            break;
        }
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
          i--;
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: I don't see any `form tag` in your code

Comment: there will be multiple `<select id="tax">` tags in the HTML?

Comment: You need different ids for each time.

Comment: The value of the element id must be unique!

Comment: I need results for all forms that i added

Comment: How its Possible @ Amit Rajput

Comment: Add your full code in question, so that i can check and solve your prob.

Comment: Your code seems not good. A lot of syntax errors...   - missing `<table>`
   - no `;` at end of lines in javascript
   - `<td>` opened and not closed with javascript in !?

Comment: I added my full code

Comment: also add your js code of "example.js"

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use same `id` for multiple elements. Element `id` must be unique. Instead, please use `class`. If you still need `id` then give a unique name.

Also for `select` use `onchange` event instead of `onblur`. In the code below, I've used `onchange` event.

Since you are using jQuery, I've updated the code with jQuery,

```
$('#dataTable').on('change', 'select.tax', function(){

    var parentElem = $(this).closest("tr");
    var tin = parseFloat(parentElem.find(".qty").val()) * 
parseFloat(parentElem.find(".prate").val());

    parentElem.find(".amt").val(tin * parseFloat($(this).val()));
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
function addRow(tableID)
  {
   var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
   if(rowCount < 20){                           
      var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
      var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
     for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
         var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
   }else{
      alert("Maximum Product submitted is 20.");

   }
 }

 function deleteRow(tableID) {
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
   for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
     var row = table.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
     if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
        if(rowCount <= 1) {                         
            alert("Cannot Remove all the Passenger.");
            break;
        }
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
          i--;
      }
   }
 }



$('#dataTable').on('change', 'select.tax', function(){
  
  var parentElem = $(this).closest("tr");
    var tin = parseFloat(parentElem.find(".qty").val()) * 
parseFloat(parentElem.find(".prate").val());
    
    parentElem.find(".amt").val(tin * parseFloat($(this).val()));
    
    alert(tin);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" method="post" class="register" action="" >

     <div id="page-wrap">

      <textarea id="header">PURCHASE</textarea>

       <div id="identity">

         <textarea id="address" disabled>AR Traders  Address:
        </textarea >


    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>

  


     <fieldset class="row2">
            <legend>Product Details</legend>
            <p> 
                <input type="button" value="Add Product" 
        onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
                <input type="button" value="Remove Product" 
      onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')"  /> 

            </p><br>
           <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
              <tbody>
                <tr class="j">
                  <p>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" 
      name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <label>Product Details</label>
                        <input type="text" required="required" 
    name="product[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <label for="brand">Brand</label>
                        <input type="text" class="small"  name="brand[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <label for="s_brand">Sub Brand</label>
                        <input type="text" required="required" class="small"  
 name="s_brand[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <label for="qty">Quantity</label>
                        <input type="text" required="required" class="small qty" 
  id="qty"  name="qty[]" onblur="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <label for="prate">Purchase Rate</label>
                        <input type="text" required="required" class="small prate" 
 id="prate" name="prate[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <label for="tax">Tax</label>
                        <select id="tax" class="tax" name="tax" required="required">
                            <option value="0">0</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                        </select>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <label for="srate">Selling Price</label>
                        <input type="text"  class="small"  name="srate[]">
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <label for="amt">Total Purchase Amount</label>
                        <input type="text" required="required" class="small amt" 
  id="amt" name="amt[]">
                     </td>
                        </p>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </fieldset>
      <input class="submit" name="add" type="submit" value="Confirm &raquo;" 
  />


  </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: you added fixed form. But i use js for adding additional forms.I do not need amt in popup window.Could you see my snippet?

Comment: Oh ok... I've updated my answer using jQuery. `select` event be triggered when you add additional forms. It's not pop window, it's an `alert` which you can comment it out if you don't want.

Comment: You are using very old version of Jquery 1.3.2... My code will work from jQuery version > 1.7

Answer (score -1):

Working example:

```js
function addRow(tableID)
{
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  if(rowCount < 20){                           
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
      var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
      newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
      count();
    }
  }else{
    alert("Maximum Product submitted is 20.");

  }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
    if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
      if(rowCount <= 1) {                         
        alert("Cannot Remove all the Passenger.");
        break;
      }
      table.deleteRow(i);
      rowCount--;
      i--;
    }
  }
}

function count(){
  $(".tax").each(function(index, e){
    $(this).on('change', function(){
      var tin = parseFloat($('.qty:eq('+ index + ')').val()) * parseFloat($('.prate:eq('+ index + ')').val());
      let total = tin * parseFloat($(this).val());
      $('.amt:eq('+ index + ')').val(total);
    })
  })   
}
count();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" method="post" class="register" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">

  <div id="page-wrap">

    <textarea id="header">PURCHASE</textarea>

    <div id="identity">

      <textarea id="address" disabled>
        AR Traders  Address:
      </textarea >

      <div id="logo">

        <div id="logoctr">
          <a href="javascript:;" id="change-logo" title="Change">Change Logo</a>
          <a href="javascript:;" id="save-logo" title="Savechanges">Save</a>
          |
          <a href="javascript:;" id="delete-logo" title="Delete logo">Delete Logo</a>
          <a href="javascript:;" id="cancel-logo" title="Cancel changes">Cancel</a>
        </div>

        <div id="logohelp">
          <input id="imageloc" type="text" size="50" value="" /><br>
          (max width: 540px, max height: 100px)
        </div>
        <img id="image" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
      </div>

    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>

    <div id="customer">
      <br>
      <textarea id="customer-title">
        Widget Corp.c/o Steve Widget
      </textarea>

      <table id="meta">
        <tr>
          <td class="meta-head">Invoice #</td>
          <td><textarea name="invoice"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="meta-head">Date</td>
          <td><input type="date" name="date" /><br></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>

    <fieldset class="row2">
      <legend>Product Details</legend>
      <p>
        <input type="button" value="Add Product" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />
        <input type="button" value="Remove Product" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

      </p><br>
      <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
            <td>
              <label>Product Details</label>
              <input type="text" required="required" name="product[]">
            </td>
            <td>
              <label for="brand">Brand</label>
              <input type="text" class="small" name="brand[]">
            </td>
            <td>
              <label for="s_brand">Sub Brand</label>
              <input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="s_brand[]">
            </td>
            <td>
              <label for="qty">Quantity</label>
              <input type="text" required="required" class="small qty" id="qty" name="qty[]" onblur="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
            </td>
            <td>
              <label for="prate">Purchase Rate</label>
              <input type="text" required="required" class="small prate" id="prate" name="prate[]">
            </td>
            <td>
              <label for="tax">Tax</label>
              <select id="tax" class="tax" name="tax" required="required">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
              <label for="srate">Selling Price</label>
              <input type="text" class="small" name="srate[]">
            </td>
            <td>
              <label for="amt">Total Purchase Amount</label>
              <input type="text" required="required" class="small amt" id="amt" name="amt[]">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </fieldset>
    <input class="submit" name="add" type="submit" value="Confirm &raquo;" />

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="terms">
      <h5>Terms</h5>
      <textarea disabled>Designed by Kshathriya Technologix.</textarea>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```